# multiple cursors in different threads running on same database

Tags: java, android, multithreading, azure, android-asynctask

I initialize a database instance in an asynctask class doInBackground(). The database instance and its methods are in a separate class (the one I will show) From the asynctask I start another thread in a class for my Azure client, which eventually queries the database class to populate my azure db client. Going back to my asynctask, I then access the db again (simultaneously as the first query) to query the db for separate information. It seems having the two cursors going simultaneously from separate threads querying is causing me problems.

Below are the methods in the db class which use the first cursor to send stuff to Azure. These methods are called from the separate thread run in an Azure class. The Azure class is called in the asynctask class. As you will see in the logcat, this works fine.

```
    public ArrayList<WeatherEvent> GetUnsychedWeatherEvent() {
    String query = COLUMN_SYNCHED + " = 0 ";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WEATHER, null, query, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<WeatherEvent> unsychedWeather = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        unsychedWeather.add( GetWeatherEvent(cursor) );
    }
    cursor.close();

    return unsychedWeather;

}

//get weather event from db for azure
//TODO: finish populating this
public WeatherEvent GetWeatherEvent(Cursor cursor) {
    WeatherEvent wEvent = new WeatherEvent();
    wEvent.Latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LATITUDE));
    wEvent.Longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LONGITUDE));
    wEvent.CurrTemp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES));
    wEvent.CurrDesc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CURRENT_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION));
    System.out.println("From DB, current temp: " + wEvent.CurrTemp);
    try {
        wEvent.Time = timeStampFormat.parseDateTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIME_STAMP)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GetEvent()", "Error parsing date " + e.toString());
    }

    return wEvent;
}
```

These next methods comes from the same db class. The 'dailycursor' here is what is causing me trouble. These methods are called in the asynctask class.

```
  public ArrayList<WeatherEvent> DailyWeatherEvents(ArrayList<WeatherEvent> dailyWeatherEvents) {
        Log.d("DB Access", "got to dailyweatherevents");

    //todo: more specific time query
    Cursor dailycursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT avg(" + COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES + "), " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", " +
            "CASE WHEN  strftime('%M', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ") < '30' " +
            "THEN strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ") " +
            "ELSE strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", '+1 hours') END " +
            "FROM " + TABLE_WEATHER +  " "+
            "GROUP BY strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", '+30 minutes')", null);

    //ArrayList<WeatherEvent> dailyWeatherEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        if (dailycursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (dailycursor.moveToNext()) {
                dailyWeatherEvents.add(GetDailyWeatherEvent(dailycursor));

            }
            dailycursor.close();
            System.out.println("Size of dailyinfo " + dailyWeatherEvents.size());
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dailyWeatherEvents;
}

public WeatherEvent GetDailyWeatherEvent(Cursor dailycursor) {
    WeatherEvent wEvent = new WeatherEvent();
   // wEvent.Latitude = dailycursor.getDouble(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LATITUDE));
  //  wEvent.Longitude = dailycursor.getDouble(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LONGITUDE));
    wEvent.CurrTemp = dailycursor.getString(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES));
    System.out.println(wEvent.CurrTemp + " mariah this comes from cursor");
    wEvent.CurrDesc = dailycursor.getString(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CURRENT_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION));
    try {
        wEvent.Time = timeStampFormat.parseDateTime(dailycursor.getString(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIME_STAMP)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GetEvent()", "Error parsing date " + e.toString());
    }
    wEvent.CurrIcon = dailycursor.getString(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CURRENT_ICONS));
    wEvent.SevereWeatherPresent = dailycursor.getInt(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SEVERE_WEATHER_PRESENT))>0;

    return wEvent;

}
```

The lines from the asynctask class that start all of this. The WeatherDBAccess is the DB class. The WeatherAzureAccess is the azure class:

```
  WeatherDBAccess._context = this.context;
            WeatherDBAccess.Instance().AddWeatherEvent(wEvent);
            //starts azure
            WeatherAzureAccess.context = this.context;
            WeatherAzureAccess.Instance();


        //prep dailyinfo arraylist

            dailyinfo = WeatherDBAccess.Instance().DailyWeatherEvents(dailyinfo);
```

And this is my logcat, the "From DB, current temp: XX" lines are printing from the methods for azure:

```
    01-12 15:15:43.869 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database HSO.sqlite
01-12 15:15:43.869 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso D/WeatherDBAccess: Instance Created /data/data/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso/databases/HSO.sqlite
01-12 15:15:43.869 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: Current Temp: 54
01-12 15:15:43.899 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: Weather Event Added
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso D/DB Access: got to dailyweatherevents
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 1, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 3 columns.
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso D/AzureAccess: WeatherSync thread STARTED!
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:451)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at pdgt.cat.com.noaahso.WeatherDBAccess.GetDailyWeatherEvent(WeatherDBAccess.java:235)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at pdgt.cat.com.noaahso.WeatherDBAccess.DailyWeatherEvents(WeatherDBAccess.java:219)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at pdgt.cat.com.noaahso.WeatherTask.doInBackground(WeatherTask.java:228)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at pdgt.cat.com.noaahso.WeatherTask.doInBackground(WeatherTask.java:47)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 49
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30189/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 49
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 49
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 49
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 50
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 50
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 50
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-29979/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso D/AsyncTask: got to onpostExecute
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
01-12 15:15:43.919 29979-30298/pdgt.cat.com.noaahso I/System.out: From DB, current temp: 51
```

Do I need to use a FutureCallback on the first cursor to know when to start the second cursor? Or do I need to make my first cursor global and wait until the first query is done before I reset the one cursor to do my second query? Looking for a solution I have learned that starting the second cursor is expensive. My problem is that the second cursor would be used rarely (possibly only onCreate()) and the first cursor will almost be always going as it's constantly used to send stuff to Azure. Also FYI I close my db onDestroy().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your error is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.

That means, that you have results (row 1), but you are trying to read an invalid column index (col -1).

The problem area is likely here:

```
wEvent.CurrTemp = dailycursor.getString(dailycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES));
```

You are getting a -1 result from `getColumnIndex` because `COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES` does not exist in your SQL query.

```
Cursor dailycursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT avg(" + COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES + "), " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", " +
            "CASE WHEN  strftime('%M', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ") < '30' " +
            "THEN strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ") " +
            "ELSE strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", '+1 hours') END " +
            "FROM " + TABLE_WEATHER +  " "+
            "GROUP BY strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", '+30 minutes')", null);
```

You need to include all columns that you intent to read from in your SELECT statement:

```
Cursor dailycursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT avg(" + COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES + "), " + COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES + ", " + COLUMN_CURRENT_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION + ", " + COLUMN_CURRENT_ICONS + ", " + COLUMN_SEVERE_WEATHER_PRESENT + ", " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", " +
            "CASE WHEN  strftime('%M', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ") < '30' " +
            "THEN strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ") " +
            "ELSE strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", '+1 hours') END " +
            "FROM " + TABLE_WEATHER +  " "+
            "GROUP BY strftime('%H', " + COLUMN_TIME_STAMP + ", '+30 minutes')", null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So why do I need to use 'SELECT COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES' and 'SELECT avg(COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMPERATURES)' in android? I don't think I understand your point because the temperature column exists, it's in the query, it's just used in the avg() function. When I run this query in my sqlite db browser it works perfectly.

Comment: That is because when you use the avg() function, the name of the column is no longer available. You can use `avg(column) as columnname` to give the dynamic column a name.

Comment: Ok that works! Would there be a more efficient way to just use one cursor instead of two? Or how I have it is fine since the second cursor won't be querying a lot of data?

Comment: Where is your second cursor?

Comment: It's the "dailycursor" initialized in DailyWeatherEvents(). 2nd chunk of code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't register your first Cursor in the first block. Well, the first query is getting everything, and the second is getting only some things. You could filter your current list and avoid polling your database for the second one. It depends if the data is changing in the database.

Comment: Hmmm I'll just keep the two cursors. First cursor is used to send stuff up to cloud storage so it's sending everything constantly and the second cursor is called ever-so-often so I'll stick to how it is and let the real developers (I'm just the engineer) optimize it. Thanks for your help!